# Get specific items from array

Tags: javascript

What I need is to get specific items (defined by array if indices) from an array.
Let say I have this source array [2,4,1,6,8] and this array of indices [0,3] and I want the result to be [2,6].
So far I am doing this to achieve the result

```
var iter = -1;
source.filter(function(item) {iter++; if (indices.indexOf(iter)>-1) {return item}})
```

Is there any more elegant solution (maybe some javascript syntactic sugar I am not aware of) than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map:

```
var source = [2, 4, 1, 6, 8];
var indices = [0, 3];

var output = indices.map(function(i){
    return source[i]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no syntactic sugar for this particular task, but a simpler way would be:

```
var destination = [];
indices.forEach(function(index) {
    destination.push(source[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to check if the original array has the index before trying to access it.

```js
var original = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var indicesSafe = [2,6];
var indicesUnsafe = [2,1234];

function filter(original, indices) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    var index = indices[i];
    
    // Check if index exists
    if (original.length > index) {
      
      // If so push onto return value
      result.push(original[index]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Safe
var resultSafe = filter(original, indicesSafe);
// Unsafe
var resultUnsafe = filter(original, indicesUnsafe);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(resultSafe);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "\n" + JSON.stringify(resultUnsafe);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
var dataArray = [2,4,1,6,8];
var indicesArray = [0,3];
var resultArray = [];

for (var i=0; i<indicesArray.length; i++) {
    resultArray.push(dataArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering a library you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#at) _.at

```
_.at(['a', 'b', 'c'], [0, 2]);
// → ['a', 'c']

_.at(['barney', 'fred', 'pebbles'], 0, 2);
// → ['barney', 'pebbles']
```